# WCF Service in .NET 4.0 goes "to sleep" but ping wakes it back up

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq

Good Morning, everyone.

I am somewhat new to WCF and we have created a new WCF service.  This service uses net.msmq bindings to transfer and receive messages from another WCF service.  This all works GREAT.  However, when we deploy the service to our servers, this new WCF service "falls asleep".  I'll explain.

I completely understand that the WCF Service doesn't run like a Windows service.  What I mean is that, once we ping the service, it'll run fine for a few minutes.  It monitors the MSMQ queues that it's supposed to and processes the messages just like it should.  Send and receive work just fine.  If there is a lull in the incoming data, the service just seems to stop listening.  It will stay in this state until we ping the service by going to the URL exposed by the HTTP service that we had to put in place.

We didn't build this to be a RESTful service, so I wouldn't expect that to be the issue.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Jim Evans, MCAD

Answer (score 1):

If the service runs under IIS it is subject to recycle timeout if there are no http requests to it. Its not clear how is the monitoring of the other service done, but without external request the IIS will put service to sleep, so perhaps change the monitored service so that it sends a notification to monitoring service.

If you have selfhosted WCF service, then please discard first paragraph, selfhosted WCF service is not affected by IIS and shouldnt go to sleep unless you turn it off.